# Aligning Conditional Controls in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction, conditional, process-control

Consider the following code

```
Manipulate[a,
 Dynamic@Grid[{
    {"Check 1", Control[{{a, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}]},
    If[a == 1, {"Check 1.1", Control[{{aa, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}]}, 
     Unevaluated[Sequence[]]],
    If[a == 1, {"Check 1.2", Control[{{ab, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}]}, 
     Unevaluated[Sequence[]]]
    },
   Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}],
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

Checking Check 1 leads to

[image]

Is it possible to use only one `If` for both controls Check 1.1 and Check 1.2?

Using `Flatten`, for example,

```
Manipulate[a,
 Dynamic@Grid[{
    {"Check 1", Control[{{a, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}]},
    If[a == 1, Flatten[{
       {"Check 1.1", Control[{{aa, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}]},
       {"Check 1.2", Control[{{ab, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}]}
       }],
     Unevaluated[Sequence[]]]
    },
   Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}],
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

I get

[image]

which is not what I want. I tried playing around with `Column` or `Row` but no success. Any ideas?

Also, is there a better or faster way of doing something like this? I'm using `Dynamic` to be able to do it, but I wonder if Mathematica already has something to do this kind of things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Apply[Sequence]` instead of `Flatten`:

```
Manipulate[a, 
 Dynamic@Grid[{{"Check 1", Control[{{a, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}]}, 
    If[a == 1, Sequence @@ 
      {{"Check 1.1", Control[{{aa, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}]}, 
       {"Check 1.2", Control[{{ab, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}]}},
     Unevaluated[Sequence[]]]}, 
   Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}], ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]